# Removing play services maps implementation from gradle

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gradle

I am trying to implement `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1` in my project, when I use this I get a warning that I shouldn't be using it along side with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`, as the first library implements everything I need for google maps.

When I remove it I can successfully build my gradle but when I run the app I am getting the following error:

```
Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1, file=/Users/name/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/25.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1, 

file=/Users/name/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/17.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1, 

file=/Users/name/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/24.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1, 

file=/Users/name/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/26.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}
```

Is there any way to 'safely' remove the library from my gradle?

Thank you.

Comment: did you remove google-services.json file?

Comment: Where will I find it? @MilaDroid

Comment: Try to clean your project before you build it (Build -> Clean Project)

Comment: I'd actually recommend *not* using `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and instead use the dedicated Maps library (the one you are trying to remove). [Play Services is now split into many libraries](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) so that you can include only the libraries that your app really needs (instead of all 20+ of them).

Comment: Well im trying to implement a FusedLocationProviderClient, in the documentation is says to use  Google Play Services. Unless you know which specific library I need.

Comment: @MarkusPenguin I have found that it is com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1. Thank you for the assistance, much appreciated. I shall use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `google-services.json` from *app/google-services.json* path.

[image]

then **Clean Project**. hope it helps :)

Comment: I dont seem to have a google-services.json file, Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of problems, deleting intermediates folder will help

try to delete it or delete debug folder in

> app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar

then rebuild your project